# Find out all combinations without repeating the first elements - JAVA

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, combinations

I've defined the next ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> Elements
```

When I fill it up it goes like this:

```
[[AAA, AAG], [GAA, GAG], [GUA, GUC, GUG, GUU], [UUC, UUU], [GAA, GAG], [CCA, CCC, CCG, CCU], [CAC, CAU], [UAC, UAU], [UAC, UAU]]
```

I need to generate all possible combinations, starting always with the first position elements of the array, which in this case are: [AAA, AAG].

f.i:

AAAGAAGUAUUCGAACCACACUACUAC

AAAGAAGUAUUCGAACCACACUACUAU

AAAGAAGUAUUCGAACCACACUAUUAC

Comment: You forgot to post your code.

Comment: Did you try something ? If yes, post it.

Comment: All possible combinations of what exactly?

Comment: @MarounMaroun in this right moment, i've no code, i've tried a few things but erased it after not working. This was yesterday

Comment: @matthelliwell all possible combinations of the first two elements in the array with the rest: f.i.: [AA],[AB,AC], [AD,AC]: AA-AB-AD, AA-AB-AC, AA-AC-AC, AA-AC-AD

Comment: (/!\ useless comment) It's about genetics isn't it ?

Comment: "A recursive function taking an index as parameter containing a for loop" is about as much as I'll help.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why:

1) Set aside the first elements of your array.

2) Generate all combinations of the remainder of your array.

3) Add back the first elements to each combination.

Does not solve your problem?